# Draw a red triangle on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a working live codepen demo at [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/xxpyRdV?editors=0010). When you click on the grid, it will draw a red square. May I know how to change the red square into a red triangle? I have tried to modify the code below. Thank you for reading and have a nice day.

```
newDot.className = 'red-dot';
// Set coordinates:
newDot.style.top = y + 'px';
newDot.style.left = x + 'px';
```

Comment: You are not actually _drawing on the canvas_ there - you are simply positioning `span` elements above it. So if you want to make those spans look like triangles, instead of their actual box shape - then use the well-known & established method, using borders. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the squares into triangles using CSS

```
clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%)
```